# Avg load page zero same with same js code for GA

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, liferay, liferay-theme

I have a Liferay server in Amazon, with different instance, each instance has their own different google analytics ID. My issue one of the instance the average load page and other static is always zero and other statics, but js code is pushing right the information to GA. The js code is the same across all the instance and only that one is showing zero in this statics. The other ones show correctly the average load page.

I've read that I could use ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});   But, if the code was the cause of the issue, why for the other liferay instances is working fine if the code is the same?.

I'm attaching the code I'm using.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
          ga('create', '$instanceCode', 'auto');

            ga("set", {
                page: '$currentURLGA',
                title: '$the_title',
                location: '$currentURLGA'
                });

            ga("send", "pageview");
            ga('send', 'event', '$roleUserMcd', 'visit page', '$restaurant',1);

    })
```

Thank you very much for your time taken.